# Streaming video output through WLAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, video, multiple-monitors, streaming

Recently, my desktop monitor broke. Since I have to wait some time for it to be repaired, I have connected an old TV with a pretty poor resolution (1366×768) and with a screen to big for me to comfortably work or play on without headaches. However, I have a laptop with a better screen (1080p and ideal size). I know it's possible to share the screen using various programs. The problem is that I don't want to mirror the screen, as it would have lower resolution (that of the old TV). Can I simply send the 1080p video output through WLAN to my HD-screen laptop, bypassing the low resolution monitor? If yes, how can I do that/what program can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is share the video files on your desktop, so that your laptop can access them via the network.  You could use any media player (such as VLC) to simply play the content on your laptop, from the shared folder.

As for playing games, this is where it gets tricky and case dependent.

For games from Steam, you are able to [stream a game from one computer to another](http://www.howtogeek.com/189601/how-to-use-steam-in-home-streaming/), as long as both computers are in the same network.  I've used this a couple of times to play games on my Linux laptop from my Windows desktop.

There are two problems with this, however; performance, and
non-Steam games.  Your frame-rate will take a bit of a hit, and you
might notice a slight delay.

You could use Remote Desktop to remote into your desktop from your laptop.  However, you will notice a definite performance hit this way.  I tried this once, and decided the delay and low frame rate was not worth it.

Comment: I didn't think about Steam Streaming, I'll check it out. Thanks, hopefully something can be done with my predicament.